# Do staff attacks do more damage to shocked enemies?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

"Shocked" is a debuff status effect in Dragon Age Inquisition that makes enemies more vulnerable to magic attacks. So I assume that using additional spells against shocked enemies does more damage to them.

What I'm unsure about is if a mage's staff attack counts as a "magic" attack. Do shocked enemies take more damage from a mage's basic staff attack, or do only spell abilities count for bonus damage?

Comment: I'm fairly certain staff attacks count as magic attacks, since mages don't use their staves as a blunt weapon. I have no evidence to back this up, though, and it's been ages since I last played the game.

Answer (score 3):

Staff attacks are counted as magic attacks and they're not used a blunt weapon, I messed around with my mage character for a while to figure this out.